# SetFit training not finishing evaluation step

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, sentence-transformers

I am trying to train a simple binary classification with SetFit, but I have a problem with the library. I use huggingface to manage my dataset. The dataset does consist of a text and a label column. If I print my dataset it looks like this:

```
dataset = load_dataset("<my-dataset>")
print(dataset)
```

with output:

```
DatasetDict({
    train: Dataset({
        features: ['text', 'label'],
        num_rows: 20
    })
    eval: Dataset({
        features: ['text', 'label'],
        num_rows: 10
    })
    test: Dataset({
        features: ['text', 'label'],
        num_rows: 135
    })
})
```

Here is my code for the training:

```
# Initialize SetFit model with a pre-trained model and define label name
model = SetFitModel.from_pretrained(
    "paraphrase-multilingual-mpnet-base-v2",
    labels=["negative", "positive"],
)

# Define the training arguments
args = TrainingArguments(
    batch_size=32,
    num_epochs=8,
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    save_strategy="epoch",
    load_best_model_at_end=True
)

# Initialize the trainer
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=args,
    train_dataset=dataset["train"],
    eval_dataset=dataset["eval"],
    metric="accuracy",
    column_mapping={"text": "text", "label": "label"}  # Map dataset columns to text/label expected by trainer
)

# Train the model
trainer.train()
```

But the problem I now have is that the training behaves very weird. I do not get any Training or Validation losses, nor do the evaluation steps ever finish. I don't know what the problem is.

[image: Overview of training]

Also please note, that I slightly changed the parameters to increase the training speed. It normally has more steps and so on. It still behaves weirdly with the normal parameters. I also use version 1.0.1 of SetFit. I haven't found any issues regarding this in the GitHub repository.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is an issue between Jupyter and SetFit!
You will see the values printed once you run your code directly in the terminal.

Sample run from the terminal here:

```
{'embedding_loss': 0.3245, 'learning_rate': 9.090909090909091e-08, 'epoch': 0.0}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            | 0/2200 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
    {'embedding_loss': 0.035, 'learning_rate': 1.1111111111111113e-05, 'epoch': 1.0}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    {'eval_embedding_loss': 0.1738, 'learning_rate': 1.1111111111111113e-05, 'epoch': 1.0}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    {'embedding_loss': 0.0005, 'learning_rate': 0.0, 'epoch': 2.0}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    {'eval_embedding_loss': 0.181, 'learning_rate': 0.0, 'epoch': 2.0}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    {'train_runtime': 156.4973, 'train_samples_per_second': 112.462, 'train_steps_per_second': 14.058, 'epoch': 2.0}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    100%|███████████████████| 2200/2200 [02:34<00:00, 14.23it/s]
    Batches: 100%|███████████████████| 46/46 [00:01<00:00, 44.09it/s]
    ***** Running evaluation *****
    Batches: 100%|███████████████████| 12/12 [00:00<00:00, 55.14it/s]
    Metrics: {'accuracy': 0.6539509536784741, 'precision': 0.6951538195187225, 'recall': 0.6539509536784741, 'f1': 0.6658552263536266}
```